# Convert dill pickle chips to bread and butter pickles?

Tags: pickles

Bread and Butter Pickles (sweet and tangy pickled cucumber slices) are not available locally (Mexico) but Costco carries dill pickle chips(slices).

Can I convert these believably?

Comment: It might be easier for people to answer this question if you explained what the two items are; I have no idea what 'bread and butter pickles' or 'dill chips' are from the names.

Comment: Basically asking if replacing some brine with sugar water overnight will be reasonably close. Maybe adding onion flakes...

Answer (score 4):

I don’t believe you’ll get a decent Bread & Butter pickle using your plan.

Dill slices are pickled in a water/vinegar/salt solution.
Bread & Butter pickles are made with a vinegar/sugar syrup.  Spices are also different between the two.

If you really want to start with the Costco dills, I would drain and rinse them well, then add the sweet syrup with appropriate spices. It will take a few days for the flavors to develop.

To make good refrigerator Bread & Butter pickles from scratch is not much more work than your plan, if you have cucumbers available (small pickling are best, and may be available at your Costco). Look for recipes online, there are plenty.

Comment: Will give small batch a go with above method for a special customer. Persian cukes available later in summer sometimes. Just not worth my bother to do scratch. Have failed before with soggy results. Thanks.

Comment: One of the places near me used to have bread and butter pickles which where thinly sliced, almost shaved.  I suspect they could be made quickly (cure time) if you had a mandoline or similar

Comment: If you use the hot marinade method for bread & butter pickles, they're ready in 1 day.

Comment: Small batch turned out very acceptable! Replaced brine with hot sugar water turmeric, onion flakes. Overnight and voilà! Since pickle is generally a small component of a burger/sandwich, will do.

Answer (score 2):

I have converted kosher dill pickles into a reasonable version of bread and butter by adding Splenda to them and refrigerating several days. I wanted a zero calorie bread and butter pickles which I was having a difficult job finding. The ones I usually buy have mustard seeds, celery seeds, and onion flakes. I am going to add those next time along with the Splenda.

Comment: Good to know, but I would recommend keeping them in the fridge, as I don’t know if Splenda acts as a preservative the same way as regular sugar.  (It might, as it’s derived from sugar, but I just don’t know)